# How to identify and remove outliers in a data.frame using R?

Tags: r, outliers, rstatix

I have a dataframe that has multiple outliers. I suspect that these ouliers have produced different results than expected.

I tried to use this tip but it didn't work as I still have very different values: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/01/how-to-remove-outliers-in-r/

I tried the solution with the `rstatix` package, but I can't remove the outliers from my data.frame

```
library(rstatix)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  sample = 1:20,
  score = c(rnorm(19, mean = 5, sd = 2), 50))

View(df)

out_df<-identify_outliers(df$score)#identify outliers

df2<-df#copy df

df2<- df2[-which(df2$score %in% out_df),]#remove outliers from df2

View(df2)
```

Comment: What is your expected output.  You said you wanted to remove the outliers and that is what it was doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `identify_outliers` expect a data.frame as input i.e. usage is

> identify_outliers(data, ..., variable = NULL)

where

> ... - One unquoted expressions (or variable name). Used to select a variable of interest. Alternative to the argument variable.

```
df2 <- subset(df, !score %in% identify_outliers(df, "score")$score)
```

Comment: Hi @Akrun. I tested the command and it just identifies the outliers. I would like him to remove too.

Comment: @wesleysc352 in that case, just negate (`!`) (updated)

Comment: @wesleysc352 i am assumnig that you wanted to use `rstatix`

Comment: Hi@akrun, after running the command, I got the error "could not find function "identify_outliers". I am new to R. Can you help me to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb is that data points above Q3 + 1.5xIQR or below Q1 - 1.5xIQR are considered outliers.
Therefore you just have to identify them and remove them. I don't know how to do it with the dependency rstatix, but with base R can be achived following the example below:

```
# Generate a demo data
set.seed(123)
demo.data <- data.frame(
                         sample = 1:20,
                         score = c(rnorm(19, mean = 5, sd = 2), 50),
                         gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), each = 10)
                        )
#identify outliers
outliers <- which(demo.data$score > quantile(demo.data$score)[4] + 1.5*IQR(demo.data$score) | demo.data$score < quantile(demo.data$score)[2] - 1.5*IQR(demo.data$score)) 

# remove them from your dataframe
df2 = demo.data[-outliers,]
```

Do a cooler function that returns to you the index of the outliers:

```
get_outliers = function(x){
   which(x > quantile(x)[4] + 1.5*IQR(x) | x < quantile(x)[2] - 1.5*IQR(x))
}

outliers <- get_outliers(demo.data$score)


df2 = demo.data[-outliers,]
```

Comment: How is your response different from @Akru's response?

Comment: I'm showing you explicitly the rule of thumb for outliers and  without dependencies explicitly removing the rows in dataframe which are outliers.